# ASP.net: Why disable AutoEventWireup improve ASP.net perfomance?

Tags: asp.net

I was reading this [wiki entry](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/667/improve-perfomance-in-aspnet/)

On point 10, it stated to disable AutoEventWireup for perfomance improvement but didn't give any reason. Isn't AutoEvenWireup is delegating? How does it improve the ASP.net performance by disable/false?

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this page on MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx)

> Do not set AutoEventWireup to true if performance is a key consideration. When automatic event wireup is enabled, ASP.NET must make between 15 and 30 tries to match events with methods.